# Using PHP to dynamically call a <title>description</title> to a webpage

Tags: php, html, xhtml

Sorry, bit of a long one...

I'm having trouble inserting a unique HTML `<title></title>` into a PHP page on my website. I'm a novice when it comes to PHP so would greatly appreciate any help or pointers you can give :).

Basically, I use a PHP script to display lots of "widgets" on my site. A visitor uses a drop-down menu to narrow the down the widgets to a single widget. The chosen widget, along with its unique attributes, are then displayed on a single page.

The problem is that the `<title></title>` on the page are all the same; I need to dynamically call the `<title></title>` according to the type of widget that is being displayed, along with the widget related attributes. So, when displayed to the user, the `<title></title>` of the page should look like this:

```
<title>Buy a Blue Widget with Stripes</title>
```

The URL and querystring currently looks like this:

```
www.foo.com/fooscript.php?widgetType=blu&widgetPattern=stri
```

So, I need a call that will recognise `widgetType=blu` references the word "Blue" and then insert that word into a specific part of the `<title></title>` tag.

Sorry its a bit of a long one, I've searched this but all I keep coming up with is WordPress tutorials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['widgetType']))
{
    switch($_GET["widgetType"])
    {
        case "blu":
            $title = "Blue";
            break;
        default:
            $title = NULL;
    }
}
?>

<title><?php if(isset($title)) { echo $title." :: "; } ?> My cool website</title>
```

Explanation in the first comment, thank you @Smejko

Comment: just to explain - the SWITCH statement is a substitue for multiple IF statements - so if your widgetType in the URL will be equal to "blu", $title will be set to "Blue"... you can add any number of CASE statements (starts with CASE, ends with BREAK;) to handle all widget types... the DEFAULT value is there if nothing will be in the widgetType variable

Comment: one more thing... add this IF statement one line before SWITCH to check whether the widgetType is set to prevent notices: if (isset($_GET['widgetType']))

Comment: Palaus Thank you for your answer. This is perfect, just what I was looking for. I really appreciate the time you have spent creating this. 

I have managed to successfully integrate the code into my webpage, and have used multiple CASE statements. I have also used it to call `widgetType`'s directly into the page body, for example in headers and descriptions. Much more than I expected to be able to do!

Comment: Say thanks to Smejko, how explained very well what the code is about. About your second question, I don't know how you can combine it. The only way will be do another switch... but i'm not sure. Anyway, now you've more code, you can post a new question with your code and let the people help you! ;-)

Comment: Palaus, will do, thanks again. @Smejko Thank you very much for such a clear explanation of the code. Has really helped and is appreciated. Cheers, Matt.

Answer (score 0):

```
<title>Buy a <?=htmlspecialchars($_GET['widgetType'])?> Widget with Stripes</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Matt you can change it too with Javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
  document.title = "The new title goes here.";
</script>
```